# select a column and replace a value if condition satisfy within the column

Tags: r

look active and if upper row is zero then replace zero with string `"xyz"`

How to write code in R?

```
Name
0
Active
0
Active
NA
Active
```

Comment: What have you tried to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You just need a standard loop:

```
for(i in 2:length(yourArray)){
   if(yourArray[i] == "active"){
      if(yourArray[i-1] == "0"){yourArray[i-1] = "xyz"}
   }
}
```